# Easy software to do 2-up, 4-up, 9-up image layout

Tags: printing, windows

My girlfriend likes to use office presentation software to arrange photos on a slide and then prints that page.  She prefers this method because she can choose the photos on the page as she goes along.  The problem comes when she has 3 or 4 pages at 4-9 images per slide.  Then the bloat becomes unbearable and she has to stop.  We've been using Open Office and I've tweaked the memory settings quite a bit, but it's not the best solution.

I'm using Win 7 and the print dialog is wonderful for putting the images that you choose into a 2,4,6,9 contact sheet arrangement.  However, this is not her preferred workflow.  She'd rather browse the directories, find the image that she likes and then cut and paste.  Once she's printed these images, then she cuts them up with scissors to make a collage book.

Does anyone know of a piece of software that would allow her to snap-in photos to some standard layouts?  ICC smart would be delightful.  Ability to cache photos from NAS would be great, too.

Comment: I think this particular question involves 'images' and software more than photography and would probably get better answers at either superuser.se or graphicdesign.se.

Comment: Apparently Photography doesn't concern "images" and "software" anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like your girlfriend would benefit from a few different approaches. One would be to look at software categorized under "album design software", the same as what a wedding photographer would use to create a wedding album. They have many templates and layouts available to do this as you will find.

Another option would be to use something like Adobe InDesign or Adobe Photoshop. Indesign will allow you basically unlimited customization for print work, while you will find Photoshop has many "actions" that will build album style pages.

I would look for a low cost or free albu